# Rotation effect on figure

Tags: floats

I want to produce a figure with this rotation effect:

[image]

I've the source code that produces this image, but I haven't been able to replicate the figure in Sharelatex, even while using the same packages. I have only been able to produce this:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp!]
  \centering
 \[
  3737616 = \overbrace{6\cdot 14^5}^{\rot{(1,1)\to (2,0,1)}} +
  \overbrace{13\cdot 14^4}^{\rot{(1,0)\to (3,1,-1)}} +
  \overbrace{4\cdot 14^3}^{\rot{(2,1)\to (1,0,-1)}} +
  \overbrace{1\cdot 14^2}^{\rot{(2,0)\to (0,1,0)}} + \overbrace{6\cdot
    14}^{\rot{(3,1)\to (2,0,1)}} + \overbrace{8}^{\rot{(3,0)\to
      (2,0,-1)}}
  \]

  \caption{Example of the Turing machine enumeration}
  \label{fig:corrWholeEx}
\end{figure}
```

The `\rot` commands are giving me trouble.

Here's the list of included packages:

```
\usepackage{algorithmic,algorithm,rotating,url}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\lstset{language=c++}
\usepackage{makeidx,multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amstext}
```

Here's a [Sharelatex link](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/55ddfb98bdfe08c7518472fd) with my attempts. I've tried the four available compilers, without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on your code. Defining a the command `\rot` you have used, as `\newcommand\rot[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\ensuremath{\footnotesize#1}}}` from the `graphicx` package, although I don't know your original implementation of the `\rot` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\rot[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\ensuremath{\footnotesize#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
 \[
  3737616 = \overbrace{6\cdot 14^5}^{\rot{(1,1)\to (2,0,1)}} +
  \overbrace{13\cdot 14^4}^{\rot{(1,0)\to (3,1,-1)}} +
  \overbrace{4\cdot 14^3}^{\rot{(2,1)\to (1,0,-1)}} +
  \overbrace{1\cdot 14^2}^{\rot{(2,0)\to (0,1,0)}} + \overbrace{6\cdot
    14}^{\rot{(3,1)\to (2,0,1)}} + \overbrace{8}^{\rot{(3,0)\to
      (2,0,-1)}}
  \]

  \caption{Example of the Turing machine enumeration}
  \label{fig:corrWholeEx}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]